# My sleep function not working for certain commands, how do I fix it? (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

[FIXED]
My sleep function used to work for all of my commands. I didn't do anything to the function but somehow it now only works for *certain* commands (in the code); like over here:

```
if (message.author.id != dev_ids) return message.channel.send("You don't have permission to use this command")

        let msg = await message.channel.send("Fetching link...")
        await sleep(2000)
        msg.edit(`Check your DMs <@${message.author.id}>`)
        message.author.send(`Bot Logs: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/***/logs\nAny problems? DM <@***>`)
```

But doesn't work for this command code (my ping cmd):

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
    name: "ping",
    description: "ping command",
    cooldown: 2000,

    async run(bot, message, args, sleep) {
        message.channel.send("Pinging... <a:870735815062462464:878533686499356683>").then(async m => {
            var ping = m.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp;

            await sleep(1000)

            var embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor("#ffffff")
                .setAuthor(`${ping}ms`)

            m.delete()
            m.channel.send("Pong! :ping_pong:", embed)
        })
    }
}
        })
```

I get an error message from the code above:

```
(node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: sleep is not a function
     at /app/commands/General/ping.js:12:19
     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
 (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
 (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:4) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code
```

Before you say the function is not defined, I have defined the function globally in my index file

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const bot = new Discord.Client();

const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://Blue_Crafter:***@***.ecxew.mongodb.net/Data', {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useFindAndModify: false
}).then(console.log('Connected to MongoDB'))

const { token } = require('./config.json');

const { readdirSync, read } = require('fs');
const ms = require('ms');

const Levels = require('discord-xp')
Levels.setURL("mongodb+srv://Blue_Crafter:***@***.ecxew.mongodb.net/Data")

const config = require('./config.json');
bot.config = config;


bot.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const commandFolders = readdirSync('./commands');
const Timeout = new Discord.Collection();

const PrefixSchema = require('./Schema/presch')

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
for (const folder of commandFolders) {
    const commandFiles = readdirSync(`./commands/${folder}`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const command = require(`./commands/${folder}/${file}`);
        bot.commands.set(command.name, command);
    }
}

bot.on("error", console.error);


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Powered on!');
    const statusArray = ['a>help, WATCHING', //More statuses];

    setInterval(() => {
        const random = statusArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * statusArray.length)].split(', ')
        const status = random[0];
        const mode = random[1];
        bot.user.setActivity(status, { type: mode })

    }, 20000);
})
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const lvlschema = require('./Schema/lvltog')
bot.on("message", async (message) => {
    const idarray = ['***']

    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.channel.type === 'dm') return; //optional#
    if (message.author.id === idarray) return


    var prefix;
    let data = await PrefixSchema.findOne({ guildID: message.guild.id })
if (data === null) { 
    prefix = "a>"
}
else { 
prefix = data.newPrefix
}

    const sleep = (ms) => { 
        return new Promise(resolve => 
            setTimeout(resolve, ms)
            );
      }

    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix)) {
        const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);

        const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();

        const command = bot.commands.get(commandName) || bot.commands.find(cmd => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(commandName));
        if (!command) return;

        if (command) {
            if (command.cooldown) {
                if (Timeout.has(`${command.name}${message.author.id}`)) return message.channel.send(`Please wait **${ms(Timeout.get(`${command.name}${message.author.id}`) - Date.now(), { long: true })}** before using this command again!`)
                command.run(bot, message, args)
                Timeout.set(`${command.name}${message.author.id}`, Date.now() + command.cooldown)
                setTimeout(() => {
                    Timeout.delete(`${command.name}${message.author.id}`)
                }, command.cooldown)
//Here is where it exports the variables
            } else command.run(bot, message, args, sleep);
        }
    }
})


bot.login(token);
```

Any fixes? I need something ASAP

Comment: Did you export the `sleep` function from `index.js` and import it in your `ping.js` file or you're just expecting it to magically appear there somehow?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros Question was edited

Answer (score 1):

In node.js, if you declare a variable inside your `index.js` file, it won't be available in your `ping.js` file. Although you say that you *"have defined the function globally"*, it's not global. It's only available inside your `index.js` file.

If you want to use this function in other files, you can export it:

```js
// index.js
// ...
const sleep = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
module.exports = { sleep }
// ...
```

and import it in other the file(s):

```js
// ping.js
// ...
const { sleep } = require('../../index.js') // make sure the path is correct
// ...
```

Now, you can use `sleep` in your other files.

Comment: I have a command handler so I use that to export the parameters like args, client, message. I exported my sleep func using my cmd handler and it worked. But now, it will only work for certain commands

Comment: Okay, ping me once edited :)